# How do I create a pull request form release branch to QA branch using git cli?

Tags: git

I want to automate to creation of pull and merge the pull from release branch to QA branch using `git cli`

I tried:

```
gh pr create --fill --head origin/qa
```

And I am getting an error:

> Warning: 1 uncommitted change
>
> Creating pull request for origin/qa into master in
> yextit/Yext-Salesforce-Sfdx
>
> pull request create failed: GraphQL: Head sha can't be blank, Base sha
> can't be blank, No commits between master and origin/qa, Head ref must
> be a branch (createPullRequest)